# Unable to populate a list using re.findall()

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm working on a simple personal project that's required I learn to use regular expressions. I have successfully used findall() once before in my program:

```
def getStats():
    playername = input("Enter your OSRS name: ")
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen("https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=" + playername) as response:
            page = str(response.read())
            player.levels = re.findall(r',(\d\d),', page)
```

This worked fine and populated the list exactly as I wanted. I'm now trying to do something similar with a text file.

The text file contains a string, followed by a lot of digits, and then another string followed by a lot of digits, etc. I just want to populate a list with the text and ignore the digits, but I get no matches (the list is empty):

```
def getQuests():
    try:
        with open("quests.txt") as file:
            q = file.read()
            questList = re.findall(r',(\D\D),', q)
            print(questList)
```

Pythex link: https://pythex.org/?regex=%5CD%5CD&test_string=Desert%20Treasure%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C12%0AContact!%2C0%2C0%2C11%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C5%0ACook%27s%20Assistant%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%0AHorror%20from%20the%20Deep%2C0%2C0%2C13&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

I've gotten some help with the pattern and edited accordingly, but the list is still printing empty

```py
def getQuests():
    try:
        with open("quests.txt") as file:
            q = file.read()
            questList = re.findall(r'^(\D+),', q)
```

Comment: copy /paste your files content into http://regex101.com - switch it to pyhton and paste your regex pattern - see whats being matched. Regex questions without data are not much worth - we cannot help if we do not see your data

Comment: What are the contents of `quests.txt`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added my pythex link with some sample text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is incorrect. Firstly, in the demo you linked, the website is not very well designed and shows adjacent matches as one single match. `\D\D` matches exactly 2 non-digit characters. Also, you didn't include the commas you have in your pattern in the code. Anyway, here is a correct pattern:

```
^(\D+),
```

It matches the start of the line, then at least one non-digit character, then a comma. The first group contains the string you want to match.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/pViF0h/2

In code:

```
import re

text = '''Desert Treasure,0,0,0,12
Contact!,0,0,11,0,0,0,5
Cook's Assistant,0,0,0,0
Horror from the Deep,0,0,13'''

print(re.findall(r'^(\D+),', text, re.M))
# ['Desert Treasure', 'Contact!', "Cook's Assistant", 'Horror from the Deep']
```

If the first entry is what you want no matter what, you can also use:

```
^(.+?),
```

Also, for these files, it is usually a much better idea to read it as a CSV and extract what you need that way.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with the pattern, greatly appreciated. I've swapped the pattern, but when I print the list it's still empty. quests.txt contains the exact text used as a sample in regex101

Answer (score 0):

Your TypeError solution is correct.

Without knowing what that webpage looks like, I do see one problem. In your working example, you use `',(\d\d),'`, but in the problem one you use `,(\D\D),`. `\d` Matches any digit characters, but `\D` matches any *non*-digits.

Comment: Two different patterns depending on the input. The first re works fine, it's the second one I'm having issues with. I've updated my OP to link to a pythex page with some sample text.

Comment: As written, `,(\D\D),` will only match things that are exactly 2 non-digit chars between commas. Try something like `(\D+),`